# Configure Apache Ignite cache with Cassandra and ODBC

Tags: caching, cassandra, odbc, ignite

I am trying to configure Apache Ignite in order to have a Cassandra-backed cache that can be queried with ODBC. I got the single components, the Cassandra cache which I am able to query using the REST api, and the a ODBC driver connection.

Now, in order to query the cache using ODBC I need to configure the [query fields](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/indexes). How can I specify the mapping between them and the fields specified in the cassandra persistence configuration?

Here is my persistence configuration for Cassandra:

```
<persistence keyspace="ignite" table="cache_test" ttl="86400">

    <keyspaceOptions>
        REPLICATION = {'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1}
        AND DURABLE_WRITES = true
    </keyspaceOptions>

    <tableOptions>
        comment = 'Cache test'
        AND read_repair_chance = 0.2
    </tableOptions>

    <keyPersistence class="java.lang.String" strategy="PRIMITIVE" column="key" />
    <valuePersistence class="java.lang.Integer" strategy="PRIMITIVE" column="value" />

</persistence>
```

Connection settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="loadBalancingPolicy" class="com.datastax.driver.core.policies.TokenAwarePolicy">
        <constructor-arg type="com.datastax.driver.core.policies.LoadBalancingPolicy">
            <bean class="com.datastax.driver.core.policies.RoundRobinPolicy"/>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="cassandraRegularDataSource" class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.datasource.DataSource">

        <property name="readConsistency" value="QUORUM"/>
        <property name="writeConsistency" value="QUORUM"/>
        <property name="loadBalancingPolicy" ref="loadBalancingPolicy"/>

        <property name="contactPoints">
            <list>
                <value>172.17.0.2</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Ignite configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- Cassandra connection settings -->
    <import resource="./connection-settings.xml" />

    <!-- Persistence settings for 'cache1' -->
    <bean id="cache1_persistence_settings" class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.persistence.KeyValuePersistenceSettings">
        <constructor-arg type="org.springframework.core.io.Resource" value="file:/home/riccardo/workspace/apache-ignite-fabric-2.0.0-bin/config/persistence-settings-1.xml" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Ignite configuration -->
    <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">

        <!-- Enabling ODBC. -->
        <property name="odbcConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.OdbcConfiguration"/>
        </property>

        <property name="cacheConfiguration">
            <list>
                <!-- Configuring persistence for "cache1" cache -->
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="cache1"/>
                    <property name="readThrough" value="true"/>
                    <property name="writeThrough" value="true"/>

                    <property name="cacheStoreFactory">
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.CassandraCacheStoreFactory">
                            <property name="dataSourceBean" value="cassandraRegularDataSource"/>
                            <property name="persistenceSettingsBean" value="cache1_persistence_settings"/>
                        </bean>
                    </property>

                    <!-- Query fields configuration -->
                    <property name="queryEntities">
                        <list>
                            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryEntity">
                                <property name="keyType" value="java.lang.String"/>
                                <property name="valueType" value="java.lang.Integer"/>
                            </bean>
                        </list>
                    </property>

                    <!-- Query fields configuration END -->
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>

        <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide list of initial nodes. -->
        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <!--
                        Ignite provides several options for automatic discovery that can be used
                        instead os static IP based discovery. For information on all options refer
                        to our documentation: http://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config
                    -->
                    <!-- Uncomment static IP finder to enable static-based discovery of initial nodes. -->
                    <!--<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">-->
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                                <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47509</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Any suggestion is really appreciated, thanks

Comment: More info needed. What are your columns in cassandra store?

Comment: @isapego updated with persistence configuration

Answer (score 1):

If I understood everything right and your cache only has key of type `java.lang.String` and value of type `java.lang.Integer` then try the following configuration:

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
    ...
    <property name="queryEntities">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryEntity">
                <property name="keyType" value="java.lang.String"/>
                <property name="valueType" value="java.lang.Integer"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    ...
</bean>
```

Comment: this was my first try too, however I get a `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "KEY" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO cache1 (key, value) VALUES ('testkey', 1)`. How do I specify the SQL schema to query, and how will it be mapped into key-value cached tuples?

Comment: You should use `_key` and `_value` instead. Like `INSERT INTO cache1 (_key, _value) VALUES ('testkey', 1)`

Comment: Almost there: `Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "CACHE1" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO cache1 (_key, _value) VALUES ('testkey', 1) [42102-195]
`. How do I configure the table name? Thank you

Comment: Add `<property name="name" value="cache1"/>` to `<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">`

Comment: So it's your Cassandra configuration. Have you chance to take a look at https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/ignite-with-apache-cassandra ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147081/discussion-between-riccamini-and-isapego).

Comment: Updated configuration

Comment: Cache name isn't the same as table name. Actualy "cache1" it is schema name while key type name is table name. Try rewrite your insert in the following way: `INSERT INTO String (_key, _val) VALUES ('testkey', 1)`